# Parsing PHP variable to Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to send an ajax call to a php page but I'm having difficulty.
My problem is parsing a variable from PHP to jQuery. I have tried for hours and I have given up. I hope someone will be able to help me!

It's working. And it is writing "Hurray!". I would like it to write my PHP-variable.....

Here is my jquery-script

```
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id){
// $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(html/images/ajaxLoader.gif) no-repeat right");
$.ajax(
{
    url: "logic/do.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: 'action=ajaxSimplePost&column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
    success: function(data)
    {
        // $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
        Messenger().post(
        {
            // var message should instead contain: the PHP variable: "myMessage".
          message: 'Hurray!',
          hideAfter: 3,
          type: "error"
        })

    }
});
}
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
if($_POST[action] == "ajaxSimplePost")
{
   $myMessage = "Yes it came through.....";
}
```

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: `function (data)` will contain the response from PHP, e.g. if you do `echo "Yes it came through";` in PHP then data will have that string in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

in your PHP file:

```
if($_POST[action] == "ajaxSimplePost")
{
  $myMessage = "Yes it came through.....";
  echo $myMessage;
}
```

And in your JQuery Script:

```
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id){
// $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(html/images/ajaxLoader.gif)     no-repeat right");
$.ajax(
{
  url: "logic/do.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: 'action=ajaxSimplePost&column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
  success: function(data)
  {
      // $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
      Messenger().post(
      {
          // var message should instead contain: the PHP variable: "myMessage".
        message: data,
        hideAfter: 3,
        type: "error"
      })
    }
});
}
```

To clarify:
your PHP file must create some output (henche the `echo`), and this output will be in `data`in your success callback.

Comment: He's right, you need that output. Just because something is a variable in one language, doesn't mean another language can understand it. Javascript has no way of knowing what is going on "under the hood" of the PHP script. Only by means of actually outputting the data, and then processing or parsing it with javascript can the two communicate. That's why this is the answer :)

Comment: Something is working :) I have a Jquery addon which is making small notices on error/success, etc. But now it is outputting the whole webpage in this notification......LOL :)
But great that something is working! Unsure why the whole page can return as "data"......?

Comment: @Nikolaj that is perfectly correct behaviour: the PHP script returns HTML (or anything that could be understood as HTML). You should have a script that only echos the desired output.